# Prove that those subspaces are $T_a-invariants$.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, invariance

Prove that, for $A ∈ O_n$, the subspaces of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices ("$M$") of $n$ order are $T_a-invariants$.

where $T_A |= A^{-1}MA$ .

---

So... ...the definition of $T_A$ implicates that every $M$ is diagonalizable for an opportune $A$?

Wikipedia says this is the spectral theorem :P...

for the definition of $O_n$ i can say $T_A= ^tAMA$
Nothing else i can say :/

Comment: and yeah i really don't have many notions about orthogonal matrices except the basic definition and something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If if $A\in O_n$ then $A^{-1}=A^T$. So if $M$ is symmetric or anti-symmetric, what does that say about the relationship between $A^{-1}MA$ and $(A^{-1}MA)^T$?

Comment: for symmetrical matrices $(A^{-1}MA)^T$=$T_A (M)$ .  This tells me that if i transpose the $T_A$associated matrix and apply it on a symmetric matrix i have the same result...

Comment: Exactly, so $M$ symmetric implies $T_A(M)$ is again symmetric, which is precisely what you need to show that symmetric matrices are a $T_A$ invariant subspace.

Comment: hum...  ...we have just transposed the expression that defines what $T_A$ does and obtained the same result. Sure that's enough to say that all the symmetrical matrices are $T_A-invariant$?

Comment: Yes, a subspace $W$ is $T$ invariant if given any element $M\in W$, we have $T(M)\in W$ as well.. In your case, $W$ is the space of symmetric matrices and the transformation is $T_A$. We transposed the result of $T_A(M)$ because we need to check if $T_A(M)^T=T_A(M)$ to determine if $T_A(M)$ is symmetric.

Comment: Yay, problem solved...    ...tomorrow will see about anti-symmetric. 1:10 am :(

Comment: So, for Antisymmetric matrices i have $ (T_A)^t=A^{-1}M^tA $...    ...$^tM$ still anti simmetric.

Comment: That is what you need to show, though what you wrote is sort of nonsense. We need to check that the transpose of the _image_ of an anti-symmetric matrix under $T_A$ is anti-symmetric The transpose of the transformation itself $(T_A)^t$ makes no sense here. So, if $M$ is anti-symmetric then $(T_A(M))^T=(A^{-1}MA)^T=\ldots=-A^{-1}MA=-T_A(M)$. You should make sure you're able to fill in the $\ldots$ there.

Comment: il M is anti-symmetric then $(A^{-1}MA)^t = A^{-1}-MA = -A^{-1}MA$ wich says the result still antisymmetric.

Comment: That's correct, though I would write $A^{-1}(-M)A$ so that it doesn't look like subtraction.

Comment: Yayyy ive got now, thanks :)